# regex back-reference not working in PHP PCRE

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I want to match matching tags like `<tag>...</tag>`. I tried the regex

```
~<([^>]+)>.*?</\1>~
```

but this fails. The expression worked when I used the exact text inside the angle brackets, i.e,

```
~<(tag)>.*?</tag>~
```

works, but even

```
~<(tag)>.*?</\1>~
```

fails.

I'm assuming that the back reference is not working here.

Can someone help me out please. Thanks

PS: I'm not using this to parse HTML. I know I shouldn't.

Comment: of course cosinder this woudl fail hard: `<a href="ciao">text</a>`. Your regex can't get that tag. I avoid to post the question of +400 when someone advise against regex for html xD. **Now you edited**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You didn't show your PHP code, but I surmise you have your regex in double quotes. If so then the backreference `\1` actually is converted into an ASCII character `☺` before it reaches PCRE. (All `\123` sequences are interpreted as C-string [octal](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) escapes there.)

Comment: Yeah. Can't see anything wrong with the regex either. So it must be some issue in PHP context.

Comment: That was it! I was using double quotes, coz I didn't know it mattered. Thanks a lot

Comment: For anyone delimiting their strings using heredoc syntax, you'll have the exact same problem. Just use the nowdoc syntax if your version of PHP supports it.

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me...

```
$str = '<a></a>';

var_dump(preg_match('~<([^>]+)>.*?</\1>~', $str)); // int(1)
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/D6Zk8p).

Also, have you considered an [XML parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)? Otherwise it won't like a piece of HTML like this...

```
<a title="Is 4 > 6?"></a>
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/5kuzqW).

Comment: The links are dead now, btw.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the fact that it's not always a good idea to try and match markup languages using regex, your regex looks OK. Maybe you're using it wrong?

```
if (preg_match('~<([^>]+)>.*?</\1>~', $subject, $regs)) {
    $result = $regs[0];
} else {
    $result = "";
}
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes in the pattern

```
preg_match_all('/(sens|respons)e and \1ibility/', "sense and sensibility", $matches);
print_r($matches);
```